# What is $\int\sinh(x)^pdx$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

What is $$\int\sinh(x)^pdx$$, where $0<p<1$?. I tried using Mathematica, but it came up with some Hypergeometric2F1 function. Is there a simpler answer in this integral?

Comment: For short: no. $\phantom{}$

Comment: The integral can alternatively be expressed as an incomplete beta function. That's likely the best you can do without being given explicit values of $p$ or limits of integration.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Is there an approximate answer for large value of $x$?

Comment: You know that for $x \to \infty$, $\sinh{x}$ goes as $e^x/2$, so...

Answer (score 2):

Extending a bit on my comment, let

$$\phi(x,p) \equiv \cosh (x) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-p}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cosh ^2(x)\right),$$ as the result of the indefinite integral thrown by Mathematica. Now, if we are interested in the limit $x \gg 1$, we may use that $\sinh{x}$ goes as $e^x/2$ (from its definition), hence:

$$\mu(x,p) \equiv \int e^{px} \, \mathrm{d}x/2^p = \frac{e^{px}}{2^pp},$$

for wich we could claim that $\phi \approx \mu$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: "This only works fairly well for p=1. Why?" Indeed, why (do you think so)?

Comment: Thank you very much @Did !

Comment: @Did, I was thinking that we should retain more than one term in the (binomial) expansion of $(e^{x}-e^{-x})^p/2^p$ if we want to gain accuracy. Correcting my (silly) mistake, I see that the real part of $\phi$ compares with $\mu$ much better than before for other $p$'s... It's obvious that for $p=1$ the "new" expression for $\mu$ is equivalent to the "old".